# Use specific layout for a model

Tags: php, layout, model, symfony1

Can anyone tell me how can I define and use a specific layout for a model (not a template)? I would like to do this for my custom 404 error page.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Layout is a component of the view.  Your 404 action can define a layout for itself.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Bailey commented above, your layout is a component of the view and has nothing to do with models.  Therefore you'd be able to do something like this in the actions module you're using (normally default):

```
public function executeError404(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->setLayout("your_layout_name");

  // ...
}
```

and then in your [APPNAME]/templates directory, create the your_layout_name.php template file as you would with any other template.